# Can I use Admob ad account and Facebook monetization account in the same Android App

Tags: android, facebook, admob, facebook-audience-network, facebook-monetization-manager

I have an android app and I'm using Google's Admob account to display ads now. Most of the time, Admob account is restricting ads and showing that ads are served limited and I don't see my ads showing on my app. Once the limitation is released I can see the ads. Now I'm planning to have Facebook Audience Network also in my App. I have created a Business account with facebook and created necessary stuff required to place a ad from facebook to my app using Facebook Monetization Manager. Now I want to know If I can use both my Admob and Facebook Audience Network accounts to show ads on my app ?

Please note that I'm planning to show a single ad on screen. Two ads won't be shown on the same screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use admob ads and facebook ads both in your app at the same time.

Prioritize your ads, lets say u want to show admob ads first and in case admobs doesn't show up, you want to display facebook network ads.
For that, you need to attach listeners to your admob ads and listen its state if admob is not loaded or if any error comes in, then you have to load/show facebook ads, and vice-versa.

For more you can head out to documentation [admob events/listeners](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner#ad_events)

Comment: Thanks Zainab for your inputs. I will implement this as per your suggestion